# MAMP doesn't start because of apache configuration

Tags: macos, apache, apache2, mamp

I have MAMP 2.1.1 installed in my Mac and I have used this one until now without problems. At this moment, I have created a virtual host and I have added the localhost.myproject to the /etc/hosts file. I have modified the file /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf with the next content:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myuser@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/web"
    ServerName localhost.myproject
    ErrorLog "logs/myproject-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/myproject-access_log" common
    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        #Order allow, deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

With this configuration apache server of MAMP starts appropriately and the log file shows:

```
[Tue May 07 09:37:02 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue May 07 09:37:02 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue May 07 09:37:02 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

but if I uncomment the line

```
#Order allow, deny
```

and I try to restart the server, apache does not start, and when I look at the log file, no lines are added to this file.

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours looking for information on Internet, I realized that a whitespace was in the line that was causing the problem. I wrote:

```
Order allow,deny
```

I restarted the server and it worked perfectly.